# There's something wrong with my shunting yards algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shunting-yard

I got some problem on working with shunting yards algorithm : I use it to parse an equation then use that equation to draw an graph, but somehow it's parsing x^2-0.5x+1 to -0.5x+1, is there anyways to fix that
Here the link to the test code : https://codepen.io/Inasaya-Flanderin/pen/ExbbgQm
This is the code part:

```
function parse(rpn) {
    let stack = [];

    Array.from(rpn).forEach((t) => {
        let tr = null;
        if (isNumber(t) || isVariable(t)) {
            tr = genNode(t, false);
        } else {
            if (Object.keys(binary_functions).includes(t)) {
                tr = genNode(binary_functions[t], true, false);

                let a = stack.pop();
                let b = stack.pop();

                if (typeof a === 'number') {
                    tr.right = genNode(a, false);
                } else {
                    tr.right = a;
                }

                if (typeof b === 'number') {
                    tr.left = genNode(b, false);
                } else {
                    tr.left = b;
                }
            } else if (Object.keys(unary_functions).includes(t)) {
                tr = genNode(unary_functions[t]);

                a = stack.pop();

                if (typeof a === 'number') {
                    tr.left = genNode(a, false);
                } else {
                    tr.left = a;
                }
            }
        }
        tr.name = t;
        stack.push(tr);
    });

    return stack.pop();
}

function eval(tree) {
    if (tree.func) {
        if (tree.unary) {
            return tree.val.eval(eval(tree.left));
        } else {
            return tree.val.eval(eval(tree.left), eval(tree.right));
        }
    } else {
        if (constant_names.includes(tree.val)) {
            return constants[tree.val];
        } else if (varnames.includes(tree.val)) {
            return variables[tree.val];
        } else {
            return tree.val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code enough to *reproduce* the problem, *inside* the question. Include the call to these functions based on a literal string, which gives the wrong output.

Comment: resolved: the problem because it's dont recognize 0.5x equal to 0.5*x

Comment: Even if you've found the problem, good form would be to update the question as recommended by trincot. so that this can serve as a useful Q&A to future readers trying to work with a JS Shunting Yard implementation.